# How to master Auto Layout

Tags: storyboard, xcode6, autolayout

The Auto Layout in Xcode 6 drives me crazy! It could be good in some cases, but most of the time I just want a simple layout, like that a view should fill the whole screen or stay at the bottom or always be centered in middle.
Are there any nice shortcuts for these standard cases? Or some techniques that makes the job done very fast?
Ctrl-dragging here and there and everywhere soon gets very time consuming when there are lots going on in the storyboard.

**EDIT:**
One nice thing I've learned: When using Assistant Editor together with storybord you can choose "Preview" at the bottom of the list and then see the result of all the constraints and see how it will look on different devices. That's a time saver.

Comment: Add your constraints in code instead of in IB.

Comment: That's an interesting thought. Especially if one could build some kind of library of standard constrain combinations. I will look into that, thanks!

Comment: Have a look at https://github.com/smileyborg/PureLayout

Comment: @Koen This code is super useful! So I upvoted the comment. But it doesn't actually answer the question, more saying "Don't Use Autolayout in Xcode"

Comment: I prefer https://github.com/SnapKit/Masonry..

For your question there is not a easy way to learn it, only practice practice practice...
If you struggle its because you don't understand it all the way, it took me a year to manage to build what ever layout I want.